# XCode 5.1 Unsupported Configuration: Multiple segues with identifier

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using the latest XCode 5.1 preview and I am now getting a lot of warning messages during build saying that "Multiple segues with identier..." is unsupported.  Any idea on this?

Comment: The appropriate place to ask about issues in development previews is the official beta forum at Apple's Developer Forum. At the same time, don't forget to file a Bug Report.

Answer (score 2):

You could make one segue by ctrl dragging from the view controller to the destination view controller. And then assuming tapping the cell is the event that you want to trigger the segue, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath call performSegueWithIdentifier.

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

Or just give the 2 segues different identifiers and in prepereForSegue check for either identifier.

and Don't try to hook up the Segues to a tableviewcell in this case. Hook them up to the View Controller itself.